# Why do Quebecers say "La"? (pronounced "law")

Tags: argot, québec

I lived in Montreal for a couple years and learned basic French, but could never figure out when/why Quebecers would use "La" (pronounced almost like a drawl "law"). It seemed (to me) like a term that was used so frequently, it could almost be tossed in at any time, whether the speaker was angry or bored, requesting feedback or making a statement. ...This thoroughly confused me.

**When is this term used and is it used more frequently in some parts of Quebec than others?**

FYI: It is not the same as the Canadian slang term "eh".
AND: This does not refer to the pronoun "la" as in le, la, les.

Answer (score 2):

In my « Dictionnaire des expressions québécoises », compiled by Pierre DesRuisseaux, the only specific entry for “LÀ” is as part of the expression:

> Ne pas être toute [tout] LÀ == être un peu timbré(e)
>   (to not be 'all there'/to be a bit crazy).

However, I suspect that the many times and different contexts of the usage that you describe in your question would be better explained by the different usages in Québéc contained on these lists for « [LÀ](http://offqc.com/2013/04/30/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-the-quebecois-use-of-la-594/) » and « [LÀ LÀ](http://offqc.com/2011/05/25/review-of-la-and-la-la-in-quebec-french/) » .

Regarding whether the use of  « LÀ » and « LÀ LÀ » is widespread in Québéc, [this site](http://oreilletendue.com/2009/07/22/la-la/) asserts that it is, with special significance in the Saguenay/Lac St Jean region (about 2-3 hours north of Québec City):

> Ce «là là» est non seulement repérable comme élément de la langue
>   courante pour tout Québécois francophone, il est aussi une allusion à
>   un trait réputé propre aux habitants de la région du Saguenay . On
>   l’entend notamment à satiété dans la bouche du maire de la ville de
>   Saguenay, Jean Tremblay, ce qui lui a valu le surnom de Jean «là là»
>   Tremblay.

Answer (score 2):

Not a native French-speaker here, but I believe that what makes *là là* different in the Saguenay region is mainly its pronunciation. In most places, the second *là* is shorter, but in the Saguenay they're both the same length. There may be a different meaning, but if there is, I doubt that's what people outside the Saguenay think of first when they hear it.

As for what *là* means, that seems like a question for an expert lexicographer. In some uses however, it seems clear that it can have the same meaning in France but is simply less frequent there. For example: *Là, tu m'agaces* or *Tu m'agaces, là* wouldn't be out of place in France, in my opinion. The only specifically Quebec usage given in the Usito dictionary is in the phrase *Là, tu parles*, which I presume to mean "Now you're talking."

I would say that *là* usually means "in this situation", "then", "now" or something along those lines. *Là là* is used in a situation where the first *là* has a full meaning, but the second là acts a bit like in the example *Tu m'agaces, là*, where *là* appears merely to emphasize the previous words. So in *Là là, tu m'agaces*, there's heavier emphasis on the fact that you're bothering me *now*. It sounds more like a warning than with just one *là*, since it seems to suggest you're reaching some limit. It wouldn't be any different in English if you said "*Now*, you're bothering me." Another example would be *Va te coucher là, là*, which means "Go to bed immediately." *Là là? - Oui, maintenant!*

You can use *là* on its own to indicate ambivalence or uncertainty: *Je sais pas, là* or *une vingtaine, là.* Or surprise: *Il y en avait vingt-trois! - Ben là!* Most commonly, it probably just means "then", as in France: *Puis là, il s'est levé* (with *puis* pronounced *pis*). "And then he got up."

Answer (score 2):

First and foremost, this is not the *article* [*la*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/la), but either the *adverb* (there, now), the *particle* which supports a demonstration, or the *interjection*: [*là*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/l%C3%A0) (with the accented character). Extracting the structure of the *Trésor* article for the latter is useful(see article for all examples/notes):

```
I. − Adv.
 A. − Emploi réflexif
  1. [Sans mouvement] Attendez-moi là; être, se trouver bien là.
   a) [Le suj. désigne une pers.] Qui est là?
   b) [Le suj. désigne une chose] Les faits sont là.
  2. [Avec des verbes de mouvement] Venez là; qui va là?
 B. − Emploi référentiel
  1. [Employé seul]
   a) [Accompagné d'un geste ou déterminé précédemment dans le discours] Dans tel lieu (autre que celui où se trouve le locuteur, désigné par lui et plus ou moins éloigné de lui).
   b) Au fig. Dans telle situation (précisée ou non), dans des circonstances données; dans ce fait (correspond à l'adv. y).
   c) [Avec une valeur simplement expressive, sert de particule explétive de renforcement, pour renvoyer à une phrase, à une circonstance désignée par le contexte]
   d) P. anal., avec valeur temporelle
  2. [Dans des loc. verb. avec en, où là signifie « à ce point, à ce degré »] En demeurer, en arriver là. 
  3. [Suivi d'une prop. sub. rel.]
   a) C'est là que
   b) Là où
  4. [Dans des loc. adv., prép. et conj.]
   a) Là + adv. ou en composition avec un adv.
    ♦ Là-bas*, v. ce mot. 
   b) Prép. + là ou en compos. avec là
    ♦ Loc. adv. De là.
II. − Particule renforçative d'un dém.
 A. −
  1. [Renforçant un pron. dém., p. oppos. à -ci (v. ci1III)] . V. celui-là, celle-là, ceux-là, celles-là.V. les formes des pron. dém.
  2. [Renforçant le gallicisme présentatif c'est, ce sont] V. supra B 1 c et B 3 a.
 B. − [Renforçant un adj. dém.] V. ce2, cet, cette, ces.
III. − Là! / là la! / là, là !, interj.
 A. − [Souvent redoublé]
  1. Vieilli. [S'emploie dans un dialogue, à l'adresse d'une pers., pour la calmer, l'apaiser, la rassurer ou l'exhorter]
  2. Mod. [En combinaison avec une autre interj. pour la renforcer]
 B. − [Sert à renforcer ce qui vient d'être dit] Fam.
  1. [En début ou en fin de phrase, pour ponctuer une assertion; sert de simple appui au discours] Synon. fam. na!
  2. [Sert à reprendre ou à préciser un terme que l'on vient d'exprimer]

[TlFi - CNRTL]
```

It is just standard *French* so you should hear it often to start with; there is no *argot* here. In the case of the *interjection*, you have such examples:

> III. A.
>
> 1. *Vieilli*. [S'emploie dans un dialogue, à l'adresse d'une pers., pour la
>      calmer, l'apaiser, la rassurer ou l'exhorter] *Là! reposez-vous; là!
>      calmez-vous; là, là, restez tranquille; là, là, ne vous fâchez pas!
>      Elle se recoucha et caressa la main du malheureux. − Là, là...
>      disait-elle. En voilà un idiot. On lui annonce qu'il n'ira plus en
>      classe et il pleure.*(Cocteau, *Enf. terr.*,1929, 1re part., p. 45).[...]
> 2. *Mod*. [En combinaison avec une autre interj. pour la renforcer]
>      *Hé là! doucement; oh là! Hep là! Ouh là! Eh là! eh là! Est-ce qu'il
>      est fou, ce gaillard-là de courir comme un dératé!.* (Courteline, *Train 8 h 47*, 1888, 1re part., p. 21).[...]
>
> B. − [Sert à renforcer ce qui vient d'être dit] Fam.
>
> 1. [En début ou en fin de phrase, pour ponctuer une assertion; sert de simple appui au discours] Synon. fam. na! *Là, c'est bien; là, c'est
>      fini; vous n'avez qu'à faire attention, là! Là, c'est bien fait!*[...]
> 2. [Sert à reprendre ou à préciser un terme que l'on vient d'exprimer] *Alors là..., mais là, là, ce qui s'appelle...; là vraiment, là franchement.*[...]

Once again, just standard *French*, if older/more familiar in some cases. Your question doesn't substantiate whether the interjection is used more frequently in Québec. Of course, you may notice a different [pronunciation](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prononciation_du_fran%C3%A7ais_qu%C3%A9b%C3%A9cois) with some speakers:

> En syllabe ouverte finale, le phonème /a/ se réalise en [ɑ] dans la
>   variété acrotectale ou [ɔ] dans la variété basilectale : « chat »
>   /ʃa/→[ʃɑ] ~ [ʃɔ], « là » /la/→[lɑ] ~ [lɔ], « sofa » /sofa/→[sofɑ] ~
>   [sofɔ], etc., d'où les alternances morphophonologique [a] : [ɑ] ~ [ɔ]
>   dans chatte : chat, plate : plat, etc.

So it may surely sound different - and there may also be further regional variations - but this is unrelated to the meaning of the word *là*. Overall this is your typical *French* language with a range of phonetic variations in Québec.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your in depth answer. This author does show that "[là is used v-e-r-y frequently during informal conversations](http://offqc.com/2011/02/15/meaning-of-la-la-in-quebec-french/)" in what he calls Quebec French.

Comment: @CanadianGirlScout Apologies, my prior comment was not so inspiring. My point is just that if we want to discuss whether the interjection for instance is used more often, then we must distinguish its use from other uses - not unlike _there_, which is used in many different ways in English. [These](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=l%C3%A0&T3.x=0&T3.y=0) can also assist with specific difficulties beyond the usage structure I presented for _là_. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

'Alors' would fit this usage pattern in France, being used as a general 'so'/'well'/'so then', with different connotations depending on intonation. 
Perhaps les Quebecois were also using this great word, but with a dropped 'a'?