# What does "la" mean in Canadian French when tacked on at the end of a sentence?

Tags: sens

I've heard `la` tacked on the end of sentences in Canadian French.

In this type of usage does `la` have any, specific, meaning?

Answer (score 3):

This usage is not limited to Canadian French, although it seems to be more common, or at least more noticed with it.

That's the interjection ***là*** (also an adverb meaning "here, now"). It reinforces what was just said.

[TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/l%C3%A0)

> **LÀ**, adv., particule et interj.
>   ...
>   **III. −** *Là! / là la! / là, là !*, interj.
>   **A. −** [Souvent redoublé]
>   ...
>   **2.** *Mod.* [En combinaison avec une autre interj. pour la renforcer] *Hé là! doucement; oh là ! Hep là ! Ouh là ! Eh là ! eh là ! Est-ce qu'il est fou, ce gaillard-là de courir comme un dératé !* (Courteline, *Train 8 h 47*, 1888, 1<sup>re</sup> part., p. 21). *Hop là ! En avant les bras ! Une carpe encore, et pas la plus mince !* (Genevoix, *Raboliot*, 1925, p. 29).
>   − *Oh là là ! Ah ! là ! là ! Ah ! là ! là ! se faire du chagrin pour les femmes ! Une de perdue, dix de retrouvées... Comme on dit* (Achard, *J. de la lune*, 1929, III, 2, p. 26). *Le moribond claquait des dents. Il bégaya : − « Oh là là... Oh là là... J'ai peur... »* (Martin du G., *Thib.*, Mort père, 1929, p. 1255).
>   **B. −** [Sert à renforcer ce qui vient d'être dit] *Fam.*
>   1. [En début ou en fin de phrase, pour ponctuer une assertion; sert de simple appui au discours] Synon. fam. *na ! Là, c'est bien; là, c'est fini; vous n'avez qu'à faire attention, là ! Là, c'est bien fait ! L'Innocent, *se levant :* Là ! j'ai fini; je n'ai plus faim* (A. Daudet, *Arlésienne*, 1872, II, 2<sup>e</sup> tableau, 5, p. 396). *Là ! ça y est; ça devait arriver ! Lettre de la petite Luce que je trouve en rentrant à la maison, dans une poche de ma serviette* (Colette, *Cl. école*, 1900, p. 173):
>   . Qu'est-ce qu'il faut vous dire encore ? J'étais si contente que vous soyez réconcilié avec moi ! Je dis : « moi », là, et je ne parle plus des autres. Arland, *Ordre*, 1929, p. 228.

As you can see, it is almost the same *là* that is found in the *[oh, là là](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/4513/what-does-the-expression-oh-l%C3%A0-l%C3%A0-mean)* phrase.

Edit: I just noticed that almost the same question was already asked: [Why do Quebecers say "La"? (pronounced "law")](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/12689/why-do-quebecers-say-la-pronounced-law)

Comment: Même si pas limité aux québécois, je suis d'accord avec jlliagre : cela me semble être un tic/gimmic de language particulièrement fréquent de ce côté là de l'Atlantique et je pense beaucoup moins du nôtre.