# L'emploi de « là » en fin de phrase (interjection, particule) est-il plus fréquent en français du Québec/Canada qu'en français métropolitain ?

Tags: oral, démonstratifs, interjections, fréquence-utilisation

L'emploi de [*là*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/l%C3%A0) comme **interjection** servant à renforcer ce qui vient d'être dit (dont on discute [ici](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/34311) et [là](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/12689)) et comme **particule** servant à renforcer un démonstratif (*...celui-là* ; ou indirectement : *...ce métier-là* ; voire un juron : *...cet ostie-là*) est-il (surtout **à l'oral**) plus fréquent **en fin de phrase** en français du Canada/Québec qu'en français métropolitain (indépendamment de [sa](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/l%C3%A0#Prononciation) [prononciation](http://phono.uqac.ca/index.php?article=rubrique31)) ?

Comment: La question n'est pas particulièrement claire. Tu t'intéresses au suffixe démonstratif *-là*, ou à l'adverbe *là* utilisé comme une interjection ? La réponse sera différente selon le cas.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Bien aux deux mais _en fin de phrase_. Il y avait une raison pour laquelle j'ai combiné les deux, c'est probablement pour contrer une perception purement phonétique du phénomène associée aux parler québécois (questions liées). Rien n'empêcherait de les traiter séparément en réponse. Autrement il me faudrait répéter essentiellement deux fois la question et le lien deviendrait ténu, je sais pas...

Answer (score 2):

Très rare en France ?  On rigole, là !

En fait ce n'est pas très courant à l'écrit, mais c'est super courant à l'oral.

Answer (score 0):

Oui, c'est certain, en France l'usage de "là" en fin de phrase est très rare. Hormis quelques phrases exclamatives comme "Ah, mais qu'il est bête celui-là !",

Notez aussi que les Suisses et les Belges utilisent "là" en fin de phrase plus souvent que les Francais.

Comment: C'est incorrect - `là` en fin de phrase est *extrêmement* utilisé dans le langage familier français: *mais qu'est-ce que tu fous, là? J'en ai marre lààà! Toujours à te plaindre et tout là!*